# MSACCESS Process hanging, errors every time after initial startup

Tags: ms-access

We've got a lot of Access databases (typically 2007) and we find this with nearly all of them as of recently. When a user launches a database it works perfectly fine until they close it down, any subsquent launches give an error on startup...

```
Execution of this application has stopped due to a run-time error
```

Users are using Access Runtime and I have access to the full version for legacy development purposes. One thing we have found is that after the first launch there's a hanging MSACCESS.exe process, if you bin it off then it fixes Access temporarily.

We have attempted compacting the databases to no avail.

Is there anyway to get a more detailed error? I have checked event viewer and also set the startup form to none, yet the issue still occurs.

Comment: You are probably looking at the wrong place (startup) when the problem is most likely on the pre-shutdown cleanup. Do your databases make any dynamic connections to other databases or files? Do they take care to properly terminate those connections? When you figure out why access is not shutting down properly you will solve your issue. If you can't or just want to band-aid it, just use a batch file for lunching a database with `taskkill` to kill any lingering `msaccess.exe` processes first before calling access runtime.

Comment: Make sure all objects are closed out (set to nothing), eg. recordsets and databases, in all your code.  Also make sure to declare Option Explicit at the top of each module, recompile, and fix any issues. I'm hoping that will stop the hanging from occuring, and therefore the error.

Answer (score 0):

Open one of the offending database and watch when the error kicks in.

That should lead to either an error message or the code window with the error highlighted.

Comment: The error only occurs in Access runtime and in that case I only get the one pop-up.

Comment: So if you open an offending database with the full Access, it runs again with no error until you later may reopen it with a run-time?